# Delete pandas group based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a pandas dataframe in with several groups and I would like to exclude groups where some conditions (in a specific column) are not met. E.g. delete here group B because they have a non-number value in column "crit1".

I could delete specific columns based on the condition `df.loc[:, (df >< 0).any(axis=0)]` but then it doesn't delete the whole group.

And somehow I can't make the next step and apply this to the whole group.

```
name    crit1   crit2
A       0.3     4
A       0.7     6
B       inf     4
B       0.4     3
```

So the result after this filtering (allow only floats) should be:

```
A     0.3     4
A     0.7     6
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `filter`, for the example you give you can check if `np.inf` exists in a group and `filter` on the condition:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda g: (g != np.inf).all().all())
#   name   crit1    crit2
# 0    A     0.3        4
# 1    A     0.7        6
```

If the predicate only applies to one column, you can access the column via `g.`, for example:

```
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda g: (g.crit1 != np.inf).all())
#   name   crit1    crit2
# 0    A     0.3        4
# 1    A     0.7        6
```

Comment: first thanks a lot for the fast reply! And if I want to apply the filtering only to one specific column (because in the others I don't care about 'inf'..) do I have to adjust on of the .all() ?

Comment: Yes. You can specify the column in the lambda function see the updated answer.

Comment: ok, that's how I imagined, but then still I'm too new to python to find it myself, thanks so much!